# Python - converting single backslash into comma

Tags: python

I have a gz file with the first 5 columns delimited by a backslash and the next 5 delimited by a comma. I'm reading in the file as follows:

```
with gzip.open(myfile, 'r') as fin:
        for line in fin:
            print line
```

The data looks like this:

```
a\b\c\d\e,f,g,h,i,j
```

How can I convert the backslashes into commas, so that it looks like this?

```
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j
```

I've tried:

```
>>> g = 'a\b\c\d\e,f,g,h,i,j'
>>> g2 = g.replace('\\', ',')
>>> g2
'a\x08,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j'
```

Reading the string in its raw format solves the problem:

```
>>> g = r'a\b\c\d\e,f,g,h,j,k'
>>> g.replace('\\', ',')
'a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,j,k'
```

But how would I read lines from a gzip'd file as raw strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just read it like you're already reading it. Reading from files doesn't apply string literal escape processing. String literal escape processing only applies to string literals.

Answer (score 0):

it exists the methods .read() and .readlines(), but don't really know if it works with gz files, try with that and use r'content'. The problem is \b, \t, \n, \u2003, and others are special caracters and using .replace('\', ',') doesn't work